# Accessing HDInsight Hive with python

Tags: python, azure, hadoop

We have a HDInsight cluster with some tables in HIVE.  I want to query these tables from Python 3.6 from a client machine (outside Azure).

I have tried using `PyHive`, `pyhs2` and also `impyla` but I am running into various problems with all of them.

Does anybody have a working example of accessing a `HDInsight HIVE` from Python?

I have very little experience with this, and don't know how to configure `PyHive` (which seems the most promising), especially regarding authorization.

With `impyla`:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
conn = connect(host='redacted.azurehdinsight.net',port=443)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM cs_test LIMIT 100')
print(cursor.description)  # prints the result set's schema
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

This gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/git/ml-notebooks/impyla.py", line 3, in <module>
    cursor = conn.cursor()
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\impala\hiveserver2.py", line 125, in cursor
    session = self.service.open_session(user, configuration)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\impala\hiveserver2.py", line 995, in open_session
    resp = self._rpc('OpenSession', req)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\impala\hiveserver2.py", line 923, in _rpc
    response = self._execute(func_name, request)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\impala\hiveserver2.py", line 954, in _execute
    .format(self.retries))
impala.error.HiveServer2Error: Failed after retrying 3 times
```

With `Pyhive`:

```
from pyhive import hive

conn = hive.connect(host="redacted.azurehdinsight.net",port=443,auth="NOSASL")
#also tried other auth-types, but as i said, i have no clue here
```

This gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/git/ml-notebooks/PythonToHive.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = hive.connect(host="redacted.azurehdinsight.net",port=443,auth="NOSASL")
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyhive\hive.py", line 64, in connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyhive\hive.py", line 164, in __init__
    response = self._client.OpenSession(open_session_req)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\TCLIService\TCLIService.py", line 187, in OpenSession
    return self.recv_OpenSession()
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\TCLIService\TCLIService.py", line 199, in recv_OpenSession
    (fname, mtype, rseqid) = iprot.readMessageBegin()
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thrift\protocol\TBinaryProtocol.py", line 134, in readMessageBegin
    sz = self.readI32()
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thrift\protocol\TBinaryProtocol.py", line 217, in readI32
    buff = self.trans.readAll(4)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thrift\transport\TTransport.py", line 60, in readAll
    chunk = self.read(sz - have)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thrift\transport\TTransport.py", line 161, in read
    self.__rbuf = BufferIO(self.__trans.read(max(sz, self.__rbuf_size)))
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thrift\transport\TSocket.py", line 117, in read
    buff = self.handle.recv(sz)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

According to the offical document [Understand and resolve errors received from WebHCat on HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-templeton-webhcat-debug-errors), it said as below.

> What is WebHCat
>
> WebHCat is a REST API for HCatalog, a table, and storage management layer for Hadoop. WebHCat is **enabled by default on HDInsight clusters**, and **is used by various tools to submit jobs, get job status, etc.** without logging in to the cluster.

So a workaround way is to use WebHCat to run the Hive QL in Python, please refer to the Hive [document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat) to learn & use it. As reference, there is a similar MSDN [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b8026143-975f-46c9-b937-99f604e3b757/connect-to-hive-in-hdinsight-using-python-app-on-remote-linuxbased-server?forum=hdinsight) discussed about it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you should be able to use the Thrift connector and pyhive but I haven't had any success with this. However I have successfully used the JDBC connector using JayDeBeAPI.

First you need to download the JDBC driver.

- http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/1.2.1/hive-jdbc-1.2.1-standalone.jar
- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.4/httpclient-4.4.jar
- http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar

I put mine in `/jdbc` and used JayDeBeAPI with the following connection string.

edit: You need to add `/jdbc/*` to your `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
       "jdbc:hive2://my_ip_or_url:443/;ssl=true;transportMode=http;httpPath=/hive2", 
       [username, password],
       "/jdbc/hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar")
```